# Initialize an in_addr_t without text parsing

Tags: c, unix

So basically I want to initialize a in_addr_t at with a specific address and parsing it from text makes no sense. It's tempting to do something like:

```
in_addr_t foo = network_byte_order(127 << 24 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 99 << 0};
```

For 127.0.0.99 and then wrapping it in a macro so it works conveniently for any address... however I want to check first if anyone know any existing macro for this, preferably "official"?

Comment: you should cast the left operands of << to uint32_t to avoid overflow, i.e #define IPADDR(a,b,c,d) (((uint32_t)a<<24) | ((uint32_t)b<<16) | ((uint32_t)c<<8) | ((uint32_t)d<<0))

Comment: use a union of char[4] and uint32?

Comment: @Gir that's undefined behavior I believe

Comment: haha... 99<<0  ....your mathematics is awesome!!! ;)

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak there could be endiannes problems and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263239/using-a-union-for-multiple-interpretations-of-ip-address

Comment: @Gir yes that still needs network_byte_order() around

Comment: @Anonymous I expect you'd also like hton8() in my software :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an existing macro for this. Look at how this example of how `INADDR_LOOPBACK` is defined in `netinet/in.h`. It's just a hexadecimal constant, an even simpler approach than yours:

```
# define INADDR_LOOPBACK        ((in_addr_t) 0x7f000001) /* Inet 127.0.0.1.  */
```

So your approach is fine.

You should use the standard `htonl()` in place of your `network_byte_order` function.